# angularjs undefined object in service

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to share data from controller 1 to another controller

I get an undefined error in my 2nd controller. Is anyone able to tell me whats wrong with my code?

**Service**

```
app.service('var_transfer_service', function(){
       var test_var;              

          return {
             getVar: function () {
                return test_var;
           },
             setVar: function( _test_var ) {
                test_var = _test_var; 
                console.log(test_var);//show the object content in my console
            }
        }
   })
```

**Controller 1**

```
app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope,$http, $filter ,var_transfer_service){
$scope.search_item = function ($event,item){
         console.log(item)
         var latt = item.lat;
         var lngt = item.lng;

         var_transfer_service.setVar(item); 
     }       

});
```

**Controller 2**

```
 app.controller('MapCtrl',function($scope,var_transfer_service, $state, $cordovaGeolocation) {
    var transferred_var = var_transfer_service.getVar();
    console.log(transferred_var); //undefined object
 });
```

Comment: Looks like your controller `MapCtrl` execute before `homeCtrl`. Show your corresponding **html** code, where use controllers.

Answer (score 1):

It's undefined because it's not initialized:

```
var test_var;
```

You only set a value on the setVar function which gets called in the $scope.search_item function in the secound controller (that you never call).

What is your indented behaviour?

Comment: all i want is to pass the item object to the second controller,,need some help on that

Comment: First of all you have to call the "search_item(...)" method. Then the getVar() method returns the set value.

Comment: when i call the "search_item(....)" methode the console.log show the object up setVar console but in getVar it is undefined in console.log

Comment: That's because the code is directly in your Controller 2 and therefore executed before the "search_item" is called. Wrapped the code in a function and call it after the search_item function!

Answer (score 0):

You used a service, but wrote a factory.

Angular services return the function instance, so put functions on the function scope, using "this".

Using service:

```
app.service('var_transfer_service', function(){
    var test_var;              
    this.getVar = function () {
        return test_var;
    };
    this.setVar = function( _test_var ) {
        test_var = _test_var; 
        console.log(test_var);//show the object content in my console
    }
}
```

Basically, angular service returns the function itself, but factory return the return value of the function - so, you wrote a factory.

So your code would work, if you will use `app.factory`:

```
app.factory('var_transfer_service', function(){
       var test_var;              

          return {
             getVar: function () {
                return test_var;
           },
             setVar: function( _test_var ) {
                test_var = _test_var; 
                console.log(test_var);//show the object content in my console
            }
        }
   })
```

Comment: it actually   give me the same result

Comment: Does homeCtrl executes before MapCtrl? Try to set `var test_var = 1` in the service, and watch if there is a change - if so, and you will see the value 1 now, than the value never gets changed.

Comment: i see the value 1, and it never changed

Comment: That means that your value never gets changed by using setVar function. There is not enough info to help from this point :/